# Shell script does not work with cron

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, cron

I have this shell script at /usr/local/1.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -r -np --user=peter --password='123' ftp://67.225.87.95/ -p /test/
```

If I run it using

```
# sh 1.sh
```

the script executes ok and does what its supposed to do.

But if I create a cron job to execute the exact same script:

```
1 2 * * * /usr/local/bin/1.sh
```

the script is not executed at all.

What could be wrong?

Comment: How the hell did you manage to add multiple lines in your title?

Comment: What do you mean by "shell script not done"? Is there any error message?

Comment: SamKrieg: "wget shell script" is the title. He has just made three lines of which are headline highlighted.

Comment: Check if wget is in the PATH of the user, whose crontab you are using.

Answer (score 2):

- Always use the full path when doing something in cron job
- Redirect all the output, error to a log file to see what happen: `1 2 * * * /usr/local/bin/1.sh > /var/log/1.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 2):

If you are going run it directly without invoking the shell interprer, you need to provide the appropriate permissions:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/1.sh
```

Otherwise, run the interpreter against its:

```
1 2 * * * /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/1.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
1 2 * * * /usr/local/bin/1.sh
```

By:

```
1 2 * * * /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/1.sh
```

**or**

Keep it:

```
1 2 * * * /usr/local/bin/1.sh
```

And prepend the following to `/usr/local/bin/1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

---

*(you may need to replace `/bin/bash` by whatever `which bash` is telling you)*